# MS Flow help on "create item" for each email address separated by semicolon within a SharePoint column

Tags: workflow

I'm using a SharePoint list with a "When Item is created" trigger to start a MS Flow.  In one specific step of my Flow, post the item creation in the trigger SP list, is to create a Task in another SP list.  Using the "Apply to Each" action in the Task SP list I want to create unique Tasks for each email address that is listed in a text field within the trigger SP list (each address is separated by a semicolon).

Currently separate, unique Tasks are being created when my Flow runs but the "Assigned To" field is blank for those tasks.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated because I haven't been able to crack this yet.

I've tried many different solutions to extract the individual email addresses for use in my "Assigned To Claims" field in my "Create Item" action within my "Apply to Each" loop, but nothing is working and I still get blank "Assigned To" tasks when they are created in my SP Task list.  I've tried numerous permutations and combinations of Data Operations and expressions (Compose, Output, split, etc.) but nothing is working.

My current MS Flow configuration fails at the "Compose" Data Operations with the error "Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Compose' inputs at line '1' and column '2616': 'The template language function 'split' expects its first parameter to be of type string."
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TX7mk.jpg)

Compose expression 
split(triggerBody()?['Facilities_x003a_Task_x0020_Emai'],';')

"Assigned to Claims" Output is using the Compose 2, Current item.